# Checking elements in a list of integers for positive or negative values

Tags: python, list

I have a predetermined created list of integers that I want to traverse and append "positive" or "negative" if the value meets the criteria. However it is throwing **"TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'** on the first line of my if statement. I have seen this error before when getting user input and must convert the input to a int, but my list is already an integer, so I am confused on what I need to fix. It is throwing the error on `if lst[i] > 0:`

```
lst = [-2, 1, -2, 7, -8, -5, 0, 5, 10, -6, 7]

for i in lst:
    if lst[i] > 0:
        lst.append("positive")
    elif lst[i] < 0:
        lst.append("negative")
    else:
        lst.append("zero")
```

Comment: Use **`i` instead of `lst[i]`**. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html. And also append the texts to another list.

Comment: You are adding to the list while traversing it, so at some point is going to compare an integer (the last one) with the first string. What is the expected output?

Comment: Why do you want the results appended to the same list?

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
[('negative', 'zero', 'positive')[((n > 0) - (n < 0)) + 1] for n in lst]
```

#### Explanation

The onliner code use list comprehension to create the list.

1. `('negative', 'zero', 'positive')` is the strings tuple from which the string will be fetched.
2. `[((n > 0) - (n < 0)) + 1]` fetch the string. Lets decompose this one:

   The subexpression (se) `(n > 0) - (n < 0)` gives the sign of n (-1 if n < 0, 0 if n == 0, +1 if n > 0)
   *Note : Python does not have a `sign` function.*

   ```
   # Keep in mind that True = 1 and False = 0
   if n < 0  'se' evaluates to False - True  => 0 - 1 => -1
   if n > 0  'se' evaluates to True  - False => 1 - 0 =>  1
   if n == 0 'se' evaluates to False - False => 0 - 0 =>  0
   ```
3. Then we add 1 to get : 0 if n < 0, 1 if n = 0, 2 if n > 0.
4. Lastly, we use this integer as an index in the strings tuple.

The equivalent code is:

```
strings=('negative', 'zero', 'positive')

def sign(n):
    """Returns the sign of n: -1 if n < 0, 0 if n == 0, +1 if n > 0"""
    return (n > 0) - (n < 0)
    
rtn = [] # will get the result
for n in lst:
    index = sign(n) + 1
    string = strings[index]
    rtn.append(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
lst = ["positive" if el > 0 else "negative" if el < 0 else "zero" for el in [-2, 1, -2, 7, -8, -5, 0, 5, 10, -6, 7]]
```

Much faster  and clean way to create what you need.

return:

```
['negative', 'positive', 'negative', 'positive', 'negative', 'negative', 'zero', 'positive', 'positive', 'negative', 'positive']
```